# Referring to great-grandparents

Tags: vocabulary, kinship

How do you refer to a specific great-grandparent? 
Does Chinese language has all 8 relationship titles to refer to one of them?

Comment: What do you refert to by all 8 relationship?

Comment: dusan means whether there's different words for: mother's mother's mother, mother's mother's father, mother's father's mother, etc. in the same way that we distinguish 祖母, 外祖母, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer is yes](http://baike.baidu.com/view/7023871.htm).

曾 is for paternal paternal ancestors, 曾外 for paternal maternal ancestors, 外曾 for maternal paternal ancestors, and 外曾外 for maternal maternal ancestors.

Comment: This is one of the aspects of Chinese that I don't think I'll ever nail down

Comment: I just wanted to add that the Wikipedia article on Chinese kinship (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_kinship#Common_extended_family_and_terminology) has tables of the various familial relationship terms.

Comment: That wiki-page is really interesting.

Comment: Another fun fact: kinship systems like Chinese in which each relation has a separate name are known as _Sudanese_, presumably after an archetypal instance.

Answer (score 2):

曾祖父, 曾祖母, 外曾祖父, and 外曾祖母 are only used in formal writings.

Paternal great-grandparents are 太爷爷/太奶奶.

(To help you memorize them, 爷爷 and 奶奶 are paternal grandparents.)

Maternal great-grandparents are 太姥爷/太姥姥 in the north and 太公公/太婆婆 in the south.

(姥爷/姥姥 and 公公（外公）/婆婆 （外婆）are maternal grandparents.)

I expect these terms to vary greatly in different regions and families. I was told to somehow call my maternal great-grandmother 太太, which also means "lady."